Removing the frame tiks portion outside of the plot
I would like to remove the frame ticks part, which is outside of the plot. How do I do that? I am using Mathematica 12.
labeledTicks=Table[{10^i, Superscript[10, i], 0.01}, {i, -60, 60, 1}]; 
labeledTicks0=Table[{10^i, Superscript[10, i], 0.01}, {i,-60,60}]; unlabeledTicks=Flatten[Table[{k*j, Null, 0.005}, {k, 2, 9}, {j,labeledTicks0[[All, 1]]}], 1]; 
myTicks=Join[labeledTicks, unlabeledTicks];
 myTicks0=Join[Flatten[Table[{k*j, Null, 0.005}, {k, 2, 9}, {j, labeledTicks[[All, 1]]}],1], Table[{10^i, Null, 0.01}, {i, -60, 60}]];

LogLogPlot[x^2, {x, 5, 100}, Frame -> True, 
 FrameTicks -> {{myTicks, myTicks0}, {myTicks, myTicks0}}, 
 ImageSize -> 500]


Adding PlotRange:
LogLogPlot[x^2, {x, 5, 100}, Frame -> True, 
 PlotRange -> {{5, 100}, {25, 10000}}, 
 FrameTicks -> {{myTicks, myTicks0}, {myTicks, myTicks0}}, 
 ImageSize -> 500]



Hi @Daniel, thank you so much for your reply. I am using Mathematica 12. It's not working. Which version are you using?

I have version 14.0
